# jquery return value

Tags: jquery

I used the following to popup a modal with grid and then returning the selected values back to parent. This worked fine in a standalone project with just one aspx page.

```
<script>

    function openDialog() {

        $("#MyModal").dialog('open');
    }

    function CloseDialog() {
        $("#MyModal").dialog('close');

        $("input#txtName").val($("input#hdnName").val());
        $("input#txtFName").val($("input#hdnFName").val());
        $("input#txtLName").val($("input#hdnLName").val());

    }

    $(document).ready(function() {

        $("#MyModal").dialog({ autoOpen: false });



        //event can fire on the click of HTML Table 
        $("#<%=grdModal.UniqueID%> tr").click(function() {
            var id = $(this).find("td:nth-child(1)").html();
            var Name = $(this).find("td:nth-child(2)").html();
            var fName = $(this).find("td:nth-child(3)").html();
            var lName = $(this).find("td:nth-child(4)").html();

            $("input#hdnId").val(id);
            $("input#hdnName").val(Name);
            $("input#hdnFName").val(fName);
            $("input#hdnLName").val(lName);
        });

        // Change the Mouse Pointer on grid row hover

        $('#<%=grdModal.ClientID%> tr').mouseover(function() {
            $(this).css({ cursor: "hand", cursor: "pointer" });
        });                    

</script>
```

I filled the gridview with a dummy datatable in codebehind.
now when i put this into my solution it doesn't return values back to parent.!!?
any clue y?? i have pasted this same code in solution.

Comment: What does "back to parent" mean?  It's all one web page, no matter how you're changing it visually with jquery.  Does the page work if you remove the jquery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try and debug the JS to get a better idea what is happening.

Does alert($("input#hdnPrincipalName").val()); produce anything?

Also what does the actual rendered HTML look like? Make sure the ID's did not get changed when the page is actually rendered.

Comment: Thanks evryone.. yes it turned out to be a typo in id.